# Problema al recorrer arreglo obtenido de una APi

Tags: php, api

Estoy realizando unas prácticas de consumo de APIs, ahora con la PokeAPI.

La consulta en cuestión puede ser la de un [rayquaza](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/rayquaza)

Mi problema es que una vez hecha la consulta y pasado los datos a la vista, no logro solamente imprimir en pantalla los nombre de los tipos del pokemon.

Mi resultado es así:

[image: resultado]

El código del backend es:

```
    $nombre_pokemon = trim(strtolower($_POST['nombre']));

    $ch = curl_init();
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'.$nombre_pokemon);
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $server_response = json_decode(CURL_EXEC($ch), TRUE);

    curl_close($ch);

    $pokemon_values['value'] = $server_response;
    $content['content'] = $this->load->view('modules/pokemon', $pokemon_values, TRUE);
    $this->load->view('master', $content);
```

Y en la vista intento recorrer el arreglo de la siguiente forma

```
    <?php foreach($value['types'] as $slot1 => $subslot1) : ?>
         <?php foreach($subslot1['type'] as $slot2) : ?>
               <?= $slot2; ?>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Hasta el segundo foreach no sé como hacer para que la url del tipo no aparezca, revisando la variable `$slot2` con la función `gettype()` me doy cuenta que su contenido son exactamente 4 strings.

Gracias de antemano, esto me sirve para poder manejar la demás información que la API me devuelve en forma de arreglos en los arreglos.

Comment: puedes hacer un print_r del contenido de $value para poder ver que información contiene y ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estuve jugando con la PokeAPI que mencionas en la pregunta y creo haber encontrado la solución a tu problema. Para esta respuesta me percaté de que puedo centrarme exclusivamente en PHP ignorando el factor de Laravel, ya que el problema radica en el primero.

Sucede que probé a consultar el API para el Pokémon **Rayquaza** que también mencionas en tu pregunta, tal que así:

```
$nombre_pokemon   = trim(strtolower('rayquaza'));

$ch               = curl_init();
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'.$nombre_pokemon);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$server_response  = CURL_EXEC($ch);
$pokemon_info     = json_decode(CURL_EXEC($ch), TRUE);

curl_close($ch);
```

Como puedes ver, he reemplazado tu `$_POST["nombre"]` por el nombre fijo del Pokémon para fines de prueba. Acto seguido, hice un [`var_dump()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php) a `$pokemon_info["types"]` para poder visualizar la estructura del JSON obtenido.

Esto es lo que obtuve:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["slot"]=>
    int(1)
    ["type"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "dragon"
      ["url"]=>
      string(34) "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/16/"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["slot"]=>
    int(2)
    ["type"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "flying"
      ["url"]=>
      string(33) "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/3/"
    }
  }
}
```

Y, basado en esta estructura, supe que bastaba con acceder al subídice `["name"]` del índice `["type"]` en cada iteración de los `$subslot`, tal que así:

```
foreach($pokemon_info['types'] as $slot => $subslot)
{
    var_dump($subslot["type"]["name"]);
}
```

Lo que demuestra, que no necesitas un segundo iterador `foreach`.

---

Aplicado a tu código, sería algo así:

```
<?php foreach($value['types'] as $slot => $subslot) : ?>
    <?= $subslot["type"]["name"]; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```